# How to insert List <T> to local database?

Tags: windows-phone

I'm use local database in window phone .When I want insert data to table I'm use code as below:

```
ObjectTopicNews topic = new ObjectTopicNews
      {
               IDCat = IdCat,
               Title=title,
               Image=image
     };
     db.listData.InsertOnSubmit(topic);
     db.SubmitChanges();
```

But I have a list data and I want insert all record of list to table and I don't know how to insert list to table,for example I want :

```
IList<ObjectTopicNews > list = getList();
db.listData.InsertOnSubmit(list );
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have iterate through list, retrieve object and insert

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/aaa25a0a-a7cb-4d44-9788-78f6d4b22355/how-to-iterate-through-list-or-ilist?forum=csharpgeneral